# Map with async returns Promise

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

The code below is returning `[Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise]` and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. What am I missing in this async function?

```
 async function testFunction(page) {

  async function multipleTests(test) {
    const tests = Array.from(test.querySelectorAll("li"));

    const allTests = tests.map((test, index) => {
      return {
        title: test.querySelector("h3").innerText
      };
    });
    return allTests;
  }


    const tests = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("section.test")).map(async test => {
      if (test.querySelector("ul li")) {
        const tests = await multipleTests(test);
        return tests;
      }
    })

    console.log(tests);

}
```

Comment: async functions always return a promise

Comment: Removing the 'async' from multipleTests should do the trick since it doesn't look like it's making any asynchronous calls

Comment: the callback of `.map` is also defined as an async function so he will need to remove this one as well

Comment: Removing the async from multipleTests didn't change the outcome. I still get an array of Promises.

Comment: I strongly recommend writing `async` JavaScript in TypeScript instead so you can catch `Promise<T>`-typing errors easily.

Comment: Remove all `async` and `await` in your code. I don't see any asynchronous task in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, assuming this is normal browser code, I don't see anything in the `.map()` part of the function that is asynchronous at all.  So, you shouldn't be using `async` there.

Second, ALL async functions return a promise.  So when you do this:

```
const allTests = test.map(async () => {...});
```

You will ALWAYS end up with an array of promises.  If you want to get the values from those promises, you would have to use `Promise.all()` as in:

```
const allTests = Promise.all(test.map(async () => {...});)
```

But, if nothing in the `.map()` callback is asynchronous, then there is no need for promises or `async` here at all - remove the `async` from the `.map()` entirely.

```
const allTests = test.map(() => {...});
```

---

Then, third in the second `.map()`, it again looks like everything is synchronous.  I think you can simplify all the code to synchronous like this:

```
function testFunction(page) {

    function multipleTests(test) {
        const tests = Array.from(test.querySelectorAll("li"));

        const allTests = tests.map((test, index) => {
            return {
                title: test.querySelector("h3").innerText
            };
        });
        return allTests;
    }


    const tests = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("section.test")).map(test => {
        if (test.querySelector("ul li")) {
            return multipleTests(test);
        } else {
            // return something else here or your tests array will have an undefined value
        }
    })

    console.log(tests);

}
```

Some points of advice to consider:

1. Do not complicate things by using `async`, `await` or promises in segments of purely synchronous code.  While `async/await` helps people write asynchronous code more easily than without, you're still dealing with promises and getting all results with `await` or eventually with `.then()` whereas synchronous code can just return or compute a value directly.
2. ALL `async` functions return a promise.  Always.  The calling code will have to use `await` or `.then()` on the returned promise to get access to the value.
3. `.map()` (long with all the array iterator methods) is NOT `async` or promise saavy.  So, when you declare an `async` callback for `.map()` that callback always returns a promise so you always end up with an array of promises.  Sometimes that's useful and what is needed, but you will then have to use something like `Promise.all()` to know when all those promises have resolved and when you can get all their values.
4. Many times with asynchronous code, it's simpler to use `async` and `await` in a plain `for` loop because the `for` construct starting in ES6 is `await` saavy and it will pause the loop for `await` making your code much simpler to write.
5. Your `tests` computation in the second part of the function looks like odd logic.  You first do a `document.querySelectorAll("section.test")` and then you again look for `test.querySelector("ul li")`.  It seems like you could just do one selector originally `document.querySelectorAll("section.test ul li")` and avoid two separate operations.